R kernel in Jupyter Notebook in HPC
I am trying to use R kernel in a Jupyter Notebook in an HPC environment. I have completed the following steps:

created a conda environment
installed latest R (4.4.1) in the environment
installed IRkernel package
ran the code: IRkernel::installspec(name='ir',displayname='R-4.4.1')

When I open the jupyter notebook through a browser, connected to the HPC, I do see the R kernel in there. Then I create a new jupyter notebook file with R kernel, which does open. When I try to run simple codes such as 2+3 it throws the following error:
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste0("png::", filename), g$width, g$height,  :
  unable to start device PNG
Calls: <Anonymous> ... evaluate -> dev.new -> do.call -> <Anonymous> -> ok_device
In addition: Warning message:
In ok_device(filename, ...) : no png support in this version of R
Execution halted

Possible solutions that I have tried:

.Rprofile -> option(bitmapType='cairo') (ref: Can't display png). I cannot find this file so cannot change it.
Reinstalling R with ./configure --with-x=yes --with-libpng=yes --enable-R-shlib --prefix=$HOME
conda install anaconda::libpng
conda install conda-forge::cairo
Installing Cairo package in R: install.packges("Cairo")

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Have you considered using R runtime on Google Colab?

Yes, I have. The data I am working on cannot be imported outside the institution and as I am not familiar with Colab's security protocols, I am not willing to use it at the moment.

Are you particular about using Jupyter notebooks, or are you open to using other IDEs for R like R Studio and the newly released Positron, which I find to be quite powerful?
